# Cannot run tizen app on Samsung TV which contains subscription flow

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv, tizen-studio

I am implementing purchase flow in Tizen web app. I've read docs from [here](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/samsung-checkout/implementing-the-purchase-process.html). When I have added the following privileges:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/sso.partner"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/billing"/>
```

I got error when installing app to the Samsung TV and when I remove these privileges, the app install successfully.
Here is the error message screenshot attached

Please let me know what I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

[image: error screenshot]